# In Java, can I use DecimalFormat to enter a dash (-) between numbers?

Tags: java, formatting, number-formatting

Can I use `DecimalFormat` to enter a dash (-) between numbers? I have been trying to do it, but somehow when I run the program the dash ends up at the end of the numbers like: 129329-

I want it to look like this: 129-329

Comment: it'd be helpful if you included the code that was putting the dash at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do this.

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;  
    import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;  

    public class NewClass  
    {  
        public static void main(String[] args)  
        {  
            DecimalFormatSymbols phoneNumberSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();  

           // Use space not comma to thousands: 10 000 not 10,000.   
           phoneNumberSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('-');   

           DecimalFormat phoneNumberFormat = new DecimalFormat("####,###,###", phoneNumberSymbols);  

           System.out.println("Some mobile number:" + phoneNumberFormat.format(567884968L));  

       }  
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your phone number is a string, here is the solution :

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;  
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;  

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long lg_tel = Long.parseLong(example.getString("tel")); // String to Long
        DecimalFormatSymbols phoneNumberSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();  

        // Use space not comma to thousands: 10 000 not 10,000.   
        phoneNumberSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('-');   

        DecimalFormat phoneNumberFormat = new DecimalFormat("####,###,###", phoneNumberSymbols);  

        (...)
        tv.setText(phoneNumberFormat.format(lg_tel).toString());  

   }
```

}